# Columns NB_ROW,NB_INS,NB_UPD,NB_DEL are all 0 in SNP_SESSIONS table in ODI 12c Metadata repository

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I am trying to find out the affected no of rows in execution of a scenario from the SNP_SESSIONS table in ODI 12c Metadata repository, but the Columns NB_ROW,NB_INS,NB_UPD,NB_DEL are all 0. Any help how to find the affected rows from the repository tables?

I looked into the SNP_SESSION table and all the columns holding affected rows information are 0. I used the below query

```
[![Select SESS_NO ,
REGEXP_REPLACE(SESS_NAME, '\w', 'x')  ,
SCEN_VERSION ,
LOG_LEVEL ,
THREAD_ID ,
THREAD_CREATION ,
TO_CHAR(SESS_BEG, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') Start_time,
TO_CHAR(SESS_END, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') End_Time,
SESS_DUR ,
SESS_STATUS ,
NB_ROW ,
NB_INS ,
NB_UPD ,
NB_DEL ,
NB_ERR ,
IND_LOG_METHOD ,
ERROR_MESSAGE 
from SNP_session 
order by sess_beg desc;][1]][1]
```

Expected the NB_XXX Columns to be populated with impacted rows, but all were 0.

[image]

Comment: Does the Operator tab in ODI Studio show different numbers for the sessions executions?

Comment: Yes it shows different numbers. I could not add the screen grab, I hope you are asking about the session ids of the sessions shown in the execution panel of Operator tab in ODI 12c.

Answer (score 0):

@Sattam, on what database you run the ODI jobs?
I discovered that when you execute statements over HIVE (for example), where statements = DELETE,INSERT,UPDATE, those informations aren't completed (nb of inserts,updates, deletes). Probably because of the communication between HIVE and Oracle and probably it replicates to other databases non-oracle.

Sorry for the comment, but I don't have enough reputation to comment to your post :)